# Vue.js: How to change images dynamically?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am working now on Exchange rates component. I have following code:

```
  <div class="list-block" v-for="(item, index) in cashData.isNoCross" :key="index + '_exchangeRateList'">
          <q-item class="list-block__element">
            <q-item-section class="list-block__section">
              <div v-for="(pic, index) in item.currency" :key="index">
                <img :src="() => getImgUrl(pic)" />
              </div>
              <span class="indent-left">{{ item.currency }}</span>
            </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
           <q-item class="list-block__element">
            <q-item-section class="list-block__section">
              <span class="title title--blue">{{ item.buyPrice }}</span>
              <div v-for="(pic, index) in item.buyStatus" :key="index">
                <img :src="() => getImgUrl(pic)" />
              </div>
            </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
    </div>
```

Here I am trying to display different icons correctly. That is, when the currency increases, the arrow is up, while decreasing down. If it has not changed, then just the dot icon. And also I have flag icons that I also need to show.

```
methods: {
getImgUrl(pic) {
  if (pic === "isUp") {
    return require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/arrow-" + pic + ".svg");
  }
   if (pic === "isDown") {
    return require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/arrow-" + pic + ".svg");
  }
   if (pic === 'unchanged') {
    return require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/arrow-" + pic + ".svg");
  }
  if (pic) {
    return require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/" + pic + ".svg");
  }
}
enter code here
```

My problem is that it can not display images.And instead of one icon for each element, it shows me three and five. Please help, I will be grateful for any answer.

Comment: You need to bind this `src` attribute to an object instead of function.

Comment: What other values can `pic` have outside of `isUp`, `isDown` and `unchanged`?

Answer (score 1):

Calling functions to render parts of your template is never a good option and the way you're trying to do it with an inline, anonymous function is simply not going to work.

I would instead provide a data property with those arrow images referenced by `pic` key and use that in your `:src` attributes, falling back to the default.

For example

```js
data: () => ({
  arrows: {
    isUp: require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/arrow-isUp.svg"),
    isDown: require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/arrow-isDown.svg"),
    unchanged: require("../../statics/icons/currency-icons/arrow-unchanged.svg")
  },
  // and any other data properties you already had
})
```

```html
<img :src="arrows[pic] || require(`../../statics/icons/currency-icons/${pic}.svg`)" />
```